# AWS S3 SDK Javascript - Build Event Work on ManagedUpload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

For Amazon S3 Javascript SDK, do the request build events as below link for PutObjects also work for managed uploads?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#build-event

I need to add a customer header. I have tried a test as below in angular:

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, params: {Bucket: 'test', Key: key, Body: body, ContentType: contentType}});

bucket
    .on('build', () =>{
      console.log('build');
      }      
    )
    .on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
      console.log('Progress', progress);      
    })    
    .send((err, data) => {
    });
```

But I am not getting a console log on build. If build doesn't apply is there any other way to apply custom headers to ManagedUploads? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The Build event is not Present on [ManagedUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html).  What headers do you need to set? Maybe there is a workaround for those.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to add nsgw-bypass as a header in order to bypass service workers in my angular app.

Comment: Maybe you can work it out with the [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) service, Or try another way to bypass the service worker.

Comment: Yeah I have found a work around, cheers